# nodejs FFMPEG add multiple inputs not working

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var proc = 
ffmpeg()
.input('./_animation/overlay1_%04d.png')
.inputFPS(20)
.input('./_animation/overlay2_%04d.png')
.inputFPS(20)
.input('./_animation/static1.png').inputFPS(1)
.input('./_animation/static2.png').inputFPS(1)
.outputFPS(20)
.save('./public/_ugc/' + new Date() + '.mp4');
```

I would like to create a video which combining from 4 sources, i.e. overlay1 sequences, overlay2 sequences and two static images. However, it is now always shows only one of the sources only. How to combine them in each of the frame?

And since the sources are not in the same dimension, is it possible to set the x,y coordinate for the sources?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ffmpeg()
    .input('./_animation/static1.png')
    .input('./_animation/overlay1_%04d.png')
    .inputFPS(20)                               
    .input('./_animation/overlay2_%04d.png')
    .inputFPS(20)
    .input('./_animation/static2.png')
    .complexFilter([
        "[0]overlay=66:155[output0]",
        "[output0][1]overlay=66:155[output1]",
        "[output1][2]overlay=66:155[output2]",
        "[output2][0]overlay=0:0[output3]",
        "[output3][0]overlay=0:0[output4]"
    ], 'output4')
    .outputFPS(20)
```

Lastly it works with the above code